# How can I resume cancelled app dowloads after attaching a Google account?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, sync, backup

I got a new phone and I signed in with my existing google gmail account. To my surprise, the phone started redownloading all of the apps I had on my other phone over my cellular data connection. Conveniently enough it was the exact same versions of the older apps I had on my old phone, and in some cases the same data preferences.

I cancelled the auto downloading, and now I can't figure out how to resume it. On the play store under `My Apps` under `all` it shows me the apps I have downloaded under that account at one point in time, but no way to mass resume downloading them. It seems to only have options for individually installing the apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the primary account on Google Play seems to continue the auto-update process

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to resume a cancelled download queue in the play store. You will have to trigger a restore again.

The only way to initialise a restore is via the setup app, so you would have to wipe again, and then let it restore. Make sure you connect to WiFi in the setup this time however.

Comment: its not the same thing, its simply a script that runs through all a list of all apps not installed but associated with that accounts. That script gets interrupted, not a giant file. The script should be able to let you continue restoring, simply based off of that list. Huge oversight, IMO

Comment: Your first statement is very confusing....?!

Comment: @CQM It is the Google backup and restore feature. The only way to trigger another restore is to rerun the setup app (wipe again). You could also download each app again manually. Otherwise, there is no way to bulk install all the apps.

Comment: I agree with @LiamW here: this looks very much like the Google Restore kicking in. And that behaves really weird: Sometimes it doesn't work at all, sometimes it really does. But when you aborted it (or it got aborted due to network failure), you're p***ed: No resume. And I've read from cases where another factory-reset just led the restore to stop exactly at the same place... But still, it's worth a try. As long as the old phone is still running, it might even fix that as it still has the complete set.

Comment: What? Really no way to trigger it again? Seems very odd...

Comment: I managed to re-trigger the restore by removing my Google account from accounts, and adding it again. No need to wipe data.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Play Store app, tap on Menu > Settings, there's the option to '*Auto update apps*' and also, '*Update over Wi-Fi only*' (This is important so not to chew up your data plan and end up with a massive phone bill), it should be noted that this is in Play Store version 3.10.10.

In that way, it will only do it over the Wifi network, and update automatically.

Unfortunately, there's no way to do a mass-resume of apps in bulk, the alternative solution is to use Titanium Backup and backup the apps to the cloud or dropbox, and let Titanium Backup do its magic in restoring from there onto the new handset, which has resumable download feature.

Comment: @LiamW please stop downvoting **just** because you *don't* like it! Let the OP find out for themselves if that's what they are looking for.

Comment: Though I agree with Liam as far as it strongly looks like the OP talks about a Google Restore kicking in (even if he's unaware of that fact, the decription strongly suggests it) -- as even that Restore uses the Playstore to download stuff, forcing the Playstore to "WiFi only" is a part of what the OP wants. I never tried it -- but it would be interesting to see whether the auto-restore would be affected by this -- though one must be pretty fast to figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible to re-trigger the app sync by going to accounts in settings, then removing your Google account and adding it again from the same menu.